# Angular - Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[] | undefined'.ts(2322) in image validation

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12 project, I am trying to validate image before submitting the form using RxwebValidators

I have this component:

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder
} from "@angular/forms"
import {
  RxwebValidators
} from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-add-validator',
  templateUrl: './image-add.component.html'
})
export class ImageAddValidatorComponent implements OnInit {
  userInfoFormGroup: FormGroup

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userInfoFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      profilePhoto: ['', [
        RxwebValidators.extension({
          extensions: ["jpeg","gif"]
        })
      ]],
    });
  }
}
```

I got this error on the component:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[] | undefined'.ts(2322)
> extension-config.d.ts(3, 5): The expected type comes from property 'extensions' which is declared here on type 'ExtensionConfig'
> (property) ExtensionConfig.extensions?: string[] | undefined

and this code is highlighted:

> extensions:["jpeg","gif"]

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: The error doesn't seem to match the code you posted. Is this the actual code and error?

Comment: @GaëlJ It is 'jpeg','gif'

Comment: @GaëlJ - what do I do?

Comment: Why negative vote? I'm finding it difficult to understand ???

Comment: Update your post with the exact code you use. Error says it's expecting an array and the code you posted do contain an array. Thus I doubt this is the real code. Or you didn't refresh properly your IDE maybe?

Comment: Checked the above code with `extensions: ["jpeg","gif"]` will not show the error, but with `extensions: "jpeg"` will show the error above. You may check on [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ma2jcc?file=src/app/image-add-validator/image-add-validator.component.ts).